# Output Voltage of Instrumentation Amplifier Configuration

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, transfer-function, instrumentation-amplifier

I'm trying to find the output voltage using the superposition theorem for this circuit configuration when RG is connected.

I'm working with ideal op amps. As far as I understand the circuit, when VB is grounded, AO2 is in non inverting configuration so Vo would be $$\left(1+\frac{R_4}{R_3+R_4} \parallel R_G\right) \times V_a$$ but I'm not sure.

When VA is grounded I don't know if there's a current through RG.

If somebody can help I would appreciate.

I've already explained my thinking about the case when VB is grounded. I think that there is current through RG, AO2 is a non inverting op amp with R4 as feedback resistor and \$(R_3+R_2) \parallel R_G\$ is the equivalent resistor.

To give you my thinking about the case when VA is grounded, well then AO2 is in inverting configuration, meaning there's a virtual ground at the inverting input, so RG is connected between 2 grounds, meaning that it has no current flowing through it. Then VO1 is \$(1+R_2/R_1) \times V_b\$.

[image: RG Is Conected]

Comment: Do you mean if Va is *grounded*

Comment: Why don't you sketch the two circuits you are trying to evaluate and figure out what Vo1 must be. Show us your work and explain your thinking. We won't do your homework for you.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson it's not about doing homework for me, it's not even a homework, I just want to understand how this circuit works. (yes, it's for school, listed as optional). I've sketched the circuit in different ways to help me visualize it better. All I was asking was confirmation if RG exists or not when Va is grounded. But to follow your objection I will explain my thinking: When VA is grounded, I think there isn't current through RG because AO2 inverting input is virtual ground, so RG would be situated between 2 grounds. So VO1 = (1+R2/R1)*VB

Comment: @ScottSeidman Yes, I was thinking in my native language that's why I wrote "shorted" because it starts with the same letter lol. I meant grounded for both Va and Vb

Comment: Please explain why you believe that the junction of R1, R2, and RG must be at ground potential for the case where VA is grounded but VB is not.

Comment: The voltage across Rg is Vb-Va

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Well, when VA is grounded, AO2 inverting input is virtual ground, RG is connected here with one terminal. The other terminal of RG is connected to AO1 inverting input, and because it is ideal op amp it has an infinite impedance, so technically there isn't current flowing from this 2 inverting inputs from one to another, that's why I consider RG out of the circuit in that case.  Also, when VA is grounded there is a current through R1 and R2, but because of the reasons explained above that current doesn't split through RG and R1, instead it goes directly to ground through R1

Comment: I think you are missing something important here. Yes, for an ideal op amp there is no **current** between the inputs. But what about the **voltage** at the inputs? Why would the current go "directly to ground through R1"?

Comment: "so RG is connected between 2 grounds, meaning that it has no current flowing through it." No, the - input of AO1 is at VB. If both inputs are at ground, then the output must be at zero, and the gain of the system is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

Question : <<< **I'm trying to find the output voltage using the superposition theorem for this circuit configuration when RG is connected.** >>>

For helping a little ... here is the literal result for output ... (E&OE). Can be perhaps simplified.

[image]

If all resistors = 10 kOhm, result is : \$Vo = -4 * VB + 4 * VA\$

Simulation. Two cases.

[image]

**<<< ... so RG is connected between 2 grounds ... >>>**

Correction: RG is connected **between 2 "virtual" "grounds" (which are different)**.

You can see this on the two simulated configurations, which are a direct Thevenin theorem application for the two inputs voltage.