# Circuit type that uses three operational-amplifiers

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I was given a problem-based learning assignment that told me to find and explain the *circuit that consists of 2 or more LM741 op-amps. Based on my research, I only managed to find a "three op-amp instrumentation amplifier." That's a circuit structure that can amplify the differential signal while stripping off any common-mode voltage. It clashes with other team's topic, though, so I'm here to ask if there is any other circuit type that fulfills the question criteria that I mentioned above.

I just need suggestions on the circuit type's name and will do the research on my own afterward.

Comment: There are basically endless possibilities. You could look into analog pulse-width modulation (pwm), just to mention one example.

Comment: It's called an Instrumental amplifier or INA for short, that uses laser-trimmer resistors for almost ideal CMRR.  120 dB = 1e6/1

Comment: A Google image search for "dual op-amp circuits" gives plenty of results. You might also be interested in [reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp) on this site.

Comment: here one : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/604113/output-voltage-of-instrumentation-amplifier-configuration/604350#604350

Comment: "problem-based learning assignment" = question!!!

Comment: @Andyaka HI there, yes indeed that's problem-based learning. But I'm here not for the answer but getting "direction/suggestion" on finding those circuit types. 
I am asking here as I kept getting the same and only result ( which is known as three op-amp instrumentation amplifiers) and this circuit has been taken by other groups.
This is why I'm here to get some help with the "direction of googling" :D
FYI, The problem-based learning assignment requires us to make a report and run a simulation to get specific data. It's not like " What's the circuit that consists of 3 amplifiers?"

Comment: Site rules: *This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the last question of your posting I can list some very versatile filter circuits.

Under B) you can find so-called "Biquadratic" or "universal filters), which - at the same time - can provide three basic filter functions: Lowpass, highpass, bandpass (bandstop).

**A)** **Two-opamp topology**:

GIC-Filters (Generalized Impedance Converter) - most versatile topologies,

**B) Three-opamp topologies**

- KHN-Filter (Kerwin-Huelsman-Newcomb),
- Tow-Thomas,
- Fleischer-Tow,
- Akerberg-Mossberg,
- Berka-Herpy,
- Parallel structures